# Splitting continuous GPS data into separate journeys

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, gps

I have a large sample of time stamped GPS data for a number of vehicles in text file format. Each vehicles data has a unique ID. I created a Pandas dataframe easily enough and then realized that the each vehicles GPS data is effectively one continuous track for several months.

What I would like to do is isolate individual journeys by splitting the track where the gap in GPS reporting exceeds a certain delta (e.g. 10 minutes). I don't think I can assume that the position does not change between the end of one journey and the beginning of the next (although it /should/ be very close).

```
uid   ts                     lat      lon
ABC   2017-01-01 00:00:00    0.0000   0.0000
ABC   2017-01-01 00:00:05    0.0000   0.0100
ABC   2017-01-01 00:00:10    0.0000   0.0200
ABC   2017-01-01 00:10:00    0.0100   0.0300 <--- New Journey. 10 min delta 
ABC   2017-01-01 00:10:05    0.0100   0.0400
ABC   2017-01-01 00:10:10    0.0100   0.0500
ABC   2017-01-01 00:10:15    0.0100   0.0600
DEF   2017-01-01 20:00:00    1.0000   1.0000
DEF   2017-01-01 20:00:05    1.0000   1.0100
DEF   2017-01-01 20:00:10    1.0000   1.0200
DEF   2017-01-01 20:20:00    1.0100   1.0300 <--- New Journey. 20 min delta 
DEF   2017-01-01 20:20:05    1.0100   1.0400
DEF   2017-01-01 20:20:10    1.0100   1.0500
DEF   2017-01-01 20:20:15    1.0100   1.0600
```

Can anyone suggest how I might efficiently go about isolating separate journeys? A solution with Pandas is absolutely not essential.

Comment: How would the new data look like? We are "isolate individual journeys".

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions. Perhaps the UID could be appended with a journey ID in a new text file? ABC-001, ABC-002? A new column in the data that gives an ID of the journey? Or even some help on what a Pandas query might look like to split data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following splits the dataframe `df` into a list of dataframes:

```
delta = pd.to_timedelta(10, unit='m')

breaks = df['ts'].diff() > delta # Feel free to add other conditions!
#0     False
#....
#6     False
#7      True
#8     False
#9     False
#10     True
#11    False
#12    False
#13    False
#Name: ts, dtype: bool

break_locs = df[breaks].index
#Int64Index([7, 10], dtype='int64')

trips = np.array_split(df, break_locs)
#[   uid                  ts   lat   lon
#0  ABC 2017-01-01 00:00:00  0.00  0.00
#1  ABC 2017-01-01 00:00:05  0.00  0.01
#2  ABC 2017-01-01 00:00:10  0.00  0.02
#3  ABC 2017-01-01 00:10:00  0.01  0.03
#4  ABC 2017-01-01 00:10:05  0.01  0.04
#5  ABC 2017-01-01 00:10:10  0.01  0.05
#6  ABC 2017-01-01 00:10:15  0.01  0.06,    uid                  ts  lat   lon
#7  DEF 2017-01-01 20:00:00  1.0  1.00
#8  DEF 2017-01-01 20:00:05  1.0  1.01
#9  DEF 2017-01-01 20:00:10  1.0  1.02,     uid                  ts   lat   lon
#10  DEF 2017-01-01 20:20:00  1.01  1.03
#11  DEF 2017-01-01 20:20:05  1.01  1.04
#12  DEF 2017-01-01 20:20:10  1.01  1.05
#13  DEF 2017-01-01 20:20:15  1.01  1.06]

len(trips)
#3
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you help DYZ! This is really helpful and I'll investigate more. I think I might need a groupby['uid'] in there somewhere in case the tracks of different vehicles overlap in time.

Comment: Just add something like  `df.uid.shift(-1).notnull() & (df.uid.shift(-1)!=df.uid)` to the condition.